# Group rows by days specifying time

Tags: mysql, group-by, mariadb

I'm trying to group a table of payments by an entire working day and payment method type (card, cash, stripe..). The thing is (and what I'm not able to accomplish) that a working day does not mean from 00:00 to 00:00 but instead it's a user input value (usually 08:00. I'm forcing 08:00 in the query now). This is because a Bar/Restaurant does not work from 00:00 to 00:00 but usually closes at 3 or 4 am. I also want to order the results by date (which I have already done).

This is the query I've gotten so far:

```
select * from (select SUM(value) as total, `currency`, `payment_method_type_id`, DATE_FORMAT(created_at, "%Y-%m-%d 08:00:00") as day from payments group by payment_method_type_id, DATE_FORMAT(created_at, "%Y-%m-%d 08:00:00"), currency) as ipd order by day desc
```

But results are not correct because time is not taken in account when grouping. I want from 08:00 of yesterday to 08:00 of today.

[Here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/p1xi2orkYBiKEBzoJ13jQ7/7)'s a fiddle with the DB Schema and some inserts.

Thanks a lot,

Comment: How do you think mysql should 'take into account' the time, when you specify `DATE_FORMAT(created_at, "%Y-%m-%d 08:00:00") as day ` in your query ?

Comment: It's an example, to avoid using vars

Comment: `Time is not taken into account`, you do mean to say that you want things grouped from yesterday 08:00 until today 08:00. If so, change your query.

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm looking for. How can I change my query if that's what I'm asking for?

Comment: We have differing interpretations of the term 'minimal'

Comment: I think I've simplified enough the example and fiddle now. Thanks

Comment: I disagree; and I've seen a few of these. There's nothing in the thousand or so rows that you've provided that couldn't be explained in 12.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't update the link after making some changes... :( I think now it's in the simplest form possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve the problem, subtract 8 yours before changing to a date.

And it can be simplified to

```
        SELECT  SUM(value) as total, `currency`, `payment_method_type_id`,
                DATE(created_at - INTERVAL 8 HOUR) as day
            from  payments
            group by  payment_method_type_id, day, currency
            order by  day desc
```

Perhaps you want the `ORDER BY` list to match the `GROUP BY` list?

Comment: Thanks! Looks like this query groups the rows correctly :)

Comment: If you are using `DATETIME`, it may give you trouble across Daylight/Standard time change.

Comment: created_at is a timestamp with UTC values